# Plot a curve of data frame

Tags: r

```
df1 <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Unique\\Desktop\\Data Science\\
                 R Scripts\\LimeBison_ch1.csv")

df2 <-  df1[df1[,3] ==  73.608125,]

plot(df2[,1],df2[,2], xlab = "Milliseconds", ylab = "Amplitude", 
  main = "Amplitude vs Time Graph",type = "p", pch =16, col = "red",
    xlim = c(-200,1200), ylim = c(-1.5,1.5))

x <- tapply(df2$Amplitude, df2$Time, mean)

df3 <- data.frame(Time = names(x), Average_Amplitude = x)
```

How can I plot a curve of the data frame df3 over the scatter plot of df2?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can provide some example data to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your data, but if you are using base plotting, then you can plot a line on top of a scatter plot by using the `lines` function

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:40, y = c(1:20, 20: 1))
plot(df$x, df$y, cex = 2)
lines(df$x, df$y)
```